# Azure Data Factory V2 : Error using the REST connector - "Failed to get schema from"

Tags: restful-url, azure-data-factory

I am doing a POC to call restFul API using ADF CopyData.

The restFul API details are available on this link

http://www.groupkt.com/post/f2129b88/free-restful-web-services-to-consume-and-test.htm

from this page, i want to rest below service
http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso3code/IND

The linked service to base URL is successfully created in ADF 
http://services.groupkt.com/country/get

in the next steps when I try to lookup data or do next steps i get error 
Error using the REST connector - "Failed to get schema from"

Let me know if you have come across this issue in ADF V2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this POC work by changing the relative URL which i was initially giving "/iso3code/IND"

Below is how the URLs should be

**Absolute URL** should be  http://services.groupkt.com/country/get : this is used for creating the Linked Service of the CopyData

**Relative URL** should be   http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso3code/IND
This is used for getting the mapping details of the Restful service